# Speaker crossover wiring

Tags: filter, wiring, speakers

Came across some old Arcam speakers (cut open) and using the parts to build a bluetooth speaker box. Only problem is I can't figure out the wiring on the crossover/filter. The original speakers are pretty old so Google didn't help much.

[image]

Image of component side
[image]

Have a 2-channel audio amp board and trying to split the signal to one tweeter and one mid on each side.This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

So question is: does anybody know what the cables are, and how can I cut/solder to achieve my goal?

Comment: Any idea where the various wires previously connected?

Comment: @mike65535 Sorry, have no idea where the cables went. All I know is that the speaker case had 4 inputs, so 4 cables went from the input to the crossover

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that connections 1 and 5 ("I") are inputs. There's a notation on the board that the input is "bi-wire" (presumably to support a bi-amp configuration).

All of the connections labeled "E" are common connections.

The connection labeled "T" goes to the tweeter. This half of the board is configured as an LC high-pass filter — capacitor in series, inductor in parallel with the load.

The connection labeled "B" goes to the bass driver. This half of the board is configured as an LC low-pass filter — inductor in series, capacitor(s) in parallel with the load.

So,

- 1 and 3 are the input from the amplifier for the tweeter
- 2 and 4 go to the tweeter itself.
- 5 and 6 are the input for the woofer (bass)
- 7 and 8 go to the woofer itself.

If you are single-amping this, then you can connect 1 and 5 together, as well as 3 and 6.